# :hover width transition glitching

Tags: html, css, hover, width, transition

I am trying to change the width of an  element when hovering over it. It appears to work, but it keeps transitioning as long as I keep the mouse over the element, resulting in a glitch-like loop. How can I make the transition to happen just once?

Thank you.

html:

```
<div>
  <div>
   <img id="img" src="#"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#img { 
  width: 326px;
  height: 326px; 
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s; 
  transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
}

#img:hover { 
  width: 0px; 
  height: 326px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering with this for a while, I realised that as the image gets smaller to `width: 0`, your cursor will eventually leave the image causing the hover state to no longer be in effect. This makes the image go back to full width until it hits your cursor again and tries to become smaller. This keeps infinitely going.

Assuming your images stay at `326px`, I edited it a bit to make the parent the same size and on the hover of the parent, it will make the child smaller. This will keep the hover area at the same size, thus not causing the glitch.

Have a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/pimhakkert/pen/YzzJyGd)